# Add a mouselistener to drawingpanel

Tags: mouselistener

I would appreciate a very simple how-to on implementing a mouseListener into a DrawingPanel. If I want to return pixels of mouse clicks, for example, how do i do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you just add a mouse listener to that drawing panel, there are a lots of tutorials.
And getting coordinates of pixels is just calling `e.getX()` and `e.getY()` methods in `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)`.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i ended up avoiding drawingpanel altogether and just went with JFrame, since adding a mouselistener is as simple as using the addMouseListener method (which doesn't seem to work with drawingpanel).